# What does super+tab mean?

Tags: keyboard, sublime-text-3

I am in debian9, a distribution of linux.
For my emmetoneline key binds setting:

```
[
{
"keys": ["super+tab"], "command": "emmet_css_from_one_line"
}
]
```

What does super+tab mean?
Which two keys will I press at the same time?
I can't find super key in my keyboard.

Comment: Windows Key...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Super key (keyboard button) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)):

> Recently "Super key" has become an alternative name for the Windows
>   key when using Linux or BSD operating systems or software that
>   originated on these systems

It is the key that looks like this:

[image]

> Why does super+tab mean?
>   Which two keys will i press at the same time?

So you will press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key + <kbd>Tab</kbd>